# use a "+" or "-" by itself without terms

Tags: math-operators, mathjax

I want to typeset an I with a subscripted "+" sign. How can I do this? I know there's a trick to tell TeX that there are no operands, but I can't remember what it is, and I can't seem to search for it on the Internet.

$I_+$

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: As far as I see, `$I_+$` is already the solution. Thus, what is the question?

Comment: Huh, I must be running into something else then. Solution confirmed. MathJax was giving me an error.

Comment: For future reference, when needed... `{+}` is a plus with no space left for operands, whereas the syntax `{}+{}` is a plus with space left for operands both left and right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comment, `$I_+` is already the solution. This seems also be working with MathJax using a [demo page](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/scaling-math/) of [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/):

> [image: Result]